# Software Installation on Dell

Tags: boot, system-installation, dvd

Installed Ubuntu 14 onto a former Windows laptop. Piece of cake. Purchased Ubuntu 16 DVD and tried to install onto another desktop. Failure galore. The desktop is a Dell Inspiron Zino HD currently running a 64-bit Windows 10 OS.

The Dell can read the Ubuntu 16 DVD during boot. I get the option of selecting Ubuntu but it fails: cannot find files or directory paths. What is the specific executable it is looking for and what is the specific directory location on the DVD. Note that I never get to the Welcome Ubuntu Install window.

I am not a programmer but I can do basic CLI interactions.

Comment: I just googled your Dell model name and this review from February 2010 popped up: [http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2360081,00.asp]. Could you provide your model number please? The model number in the review is `400`. If it's running Windows 10 it's unlikely to be from 2010 right???